# How to reload a ruby class

Tags: ruby, rspec

In many of our classes we cache expensive operation for performance. e.g.

```
def self.foo
    @foo ||= get_foo
end
```

This works great in the application, however the tests (RSpec) fail because of these memoized variables. The values from the first test are being returned in the subsequent tests, when we expect fresh values.

So the question is: how do I reload the class? Or remove all the memoized variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Build your classes and tests in such a way that the cached data remains correct or gets deleted when it is invalid. Consider adding a method to clear the cache and calling it in a rspec `before` block.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the best approach and cleaner solution. thanks

Answer (score 9):

Add an `after` (or `before`) block to the example group to remove the instance variable (assuming the object in question is the subject):

```
after do
  subject.instance_variable_set(:@foo, nil)
end
```

Or *fix the problem*. Having a memoized class instance variable is a bit of a smell since it will never change. Normal instance variables wouldn't have this issue since you'd create a new object for each test.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that will work too, but same issue as the other solution, this will make test maintenance difficult as you need to explicitly unset variables

Comment: Yeah, I am inclined to not do the memoization in the first place.

Comment: Yup. As a general guideline: if it's hard to right your tests, it's really the tested code that's wrong.

Comment: What about when you're memoizing config values? Is that still a bad practice? e.g. `@key ||= File.read(key_file_path)`